# MySQL group by x characters on an id field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a client database that is in a pretty poor state, but I have to work with it. We have a set of product id's and each id is made up of the attributes of the product. What i'd like to do is select those id's that match the first 4 or 5 characters and have them in a drop down box as variants of a selected product.

I've tried 'group by subtr(0,6)', but this seems to return only the first match in the group. What I need is to have separate queries, that ONLY return ALL the individual rows that have a matching first x characters.

So, for example, I want to have queries that will return:
12345xx
12345yy
12345zz

and then another that will return: 
56789xx
56789yy
56789zz

This following query would return only:

12345xx

and then

56789yy for example

```
select tbl_item.Description, tbl_item.`Description 2`, tbl_item.`Inventory Posting Group`, tbl_item.No_, tbl_item.`Web Description`, tbl_item.`Web Headers`, tbl_item.`Unit Price`, tbl_item.`Sales (Qty_)`, tbl_item.`Product Group Code`
from tbl_item
where tbl_item.`Product Group Code` = ':shopprodid' and tbl_item.`Vendor No_` = '$vendor_no'
group by substr(0,6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to put the substr and LIKE in the WHERE clause (no need to group anything). And btw, in MySql the substring starts at index 1, not 0.

```
select *
from tbl_item
where substr(tbl_item.`Product Group Code`, 1, 6) LIKE ':shopprodid%'
```

Comment: Thank you. This syntax looks interesting, is the colon making that a variable reference?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it seems to be replacing "$_GET" with a :

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following;

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_item WHERE SUBSTR([<Column name>], 1, 6) = '<Your ID prefix>' ORDER BY [<Column name>]
```

Comment: Or just look for entries that begins with your prefix. WHERE <Column> LIKE = '<prefix>%'

Comment: Thank you. I don't know the prefixes in advance, I only know a subset of products via a vendor id. Hence, why I wanted to group the results, but 'group by' only returns one match for the 'group'. I *think* what you have suggested with the wildcard might just work, but I was hoping to minimise queries to the db. I'll have a play and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `substr(0,6)`? the correct syntax is

```
SUBSTR( str, pos, len )
```

I suppose you mean:

```
SUBSTR( tbl_item.id, 0, 6 )
```

correct that.

And for the results you want you don't need the substr at all, use a query like this:

```
SELECT * from tbl_item WHERE tbl_item.id LIKE '12345%'
```

Comment: Yes, thanks the code was as you say, with the column name, but I added it here in error, so apologies. I will have a go with the wildcard, but not sure it is quite what I need. Will try.